# How do you set up an UIImageView to point to another UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I want to have a pointer to an UIImage view so that I don't have to repeat a lot of my code.  I need to choose the image based on which button it is but then at the end I apply the same code to whatever digit.  `oneDigit`, `twoDigit`, and `threeDigit` are all `@property(nonatomic, retain)` in the header file. I want imageView to be able to point to one of these UIImageViews.  Right now the UIImageViews are not being removed with `removeFromSuperview` because `imageView` is not pointing to the objects but creating its own object..

Currently when a button is pressed a Image is added.  I want the previous image removed and the new image drawn according to what button was pressed. The code works how I want if I replace imageView with oneDigit, but that would require me to add more code for each variable.

See simplified example below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   ...
    UIImageView *oneDigit;
    UIImageView *twoDigit;
    UIImageView *threeDigit;
}

-(IBAction)pressButton:(id)sender {
    UIImage *image;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;
    int value = [btn.titleLabel.text intValue];
    switch (value) {
        case 10:
        case 15:
        case 20:
            [twoDigit removeFromSuperview]; //Remove old image from screen
            imageView = twoDigit; //Update imageView pointer for current case
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twoDigit.png"];
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            [oneDigit removeFromSuperview];
            imageView = oneDigit;
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oneDigit.png"];
            break;
        case 100:
        case 200:
        case 300:
            [threeDigit removeFromSuperview];
            imageView = threeDigit;
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"threeDigit.png"];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    CGPoint point = btn.frame.origin;
    CGFloat xposition = point.x - ((image.size.width - btn.frame.size.width) /2);
    CGFloat yposition = point.y - ((image.size.height - btn.frame.size.height) /2);
    imageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xposition, yposition, image.size.width, image.size.height) ];
    imageView.image = image;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: You "want to have a pointer to an UIImageView", and your code contains a pointer to a UIImageView.  What's the actual question?  What don't you like about the code?

Comment: When and where are you assigning values to `oneDigit`, `twoDigit` and `threeDigit`? In each of your case statements you send the `removeFromSuperView` message to these, and then assign them to the `imageView`. Then you create a new `UIImageView` and assign it to `imageView`. Surely whatever you have initialised `oneDigit`, etc to is then lost?

Comment: Updated question. I want imageView to point to oneDigit so that the code at the end of the method can be used for all cases but when the method is ran again it will remove oneDigit from the screen. Using imageView it doesn't remove anything from the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that oneDigit, twoDigit and threeDigit are UIImageViews, you can just do something similar to

```
imageView = oneDigit;
```

Since both are pointers, setting imageView to oneDigit will simply point imageView to the location of oneDigit. When you set it to the new image, don't autorelease it first, because if it's set to threeDigit for example, it will autorelease threeDigit too.

Also, you don't need to set the image property of imageView manually after setting imageView to the new image, because it's essentially referencing the exact same UIImageView with the same image; it's just under a different name.

Comment: I'm not doing any autoreleasing, because I am in ARC mode.  This is not working because it is drawing the image multiple times in the different locations. I want the image to be removed, and then redrawn in a new location using the appropriate image.

Comment: That's because you're initialising imageView at the bottom of the code, which means it doesn't point to oneDigit any more, but instead to a new object. What you should do at the bottom instead of initialising it and setting the image property, is set the frame of the imageView to the new frame you want.

Comment: Thank you. I've been modifying the code so much I didn't catch that. I think this is what I need to do but I got something wrong again, I modified that line to `imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xposition, yposition, image.size.width, image.size.height);` and then put `UIImageView *imageView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] init];` before the switch but its not working still.  What did I overlook this time?